# unable to start angular2 project generated with angular-cli due to getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Mac, OSX El Capitan 10.11.2, and trying to start angular2 application using angular-cli. As per document I have run the following

```
$sudo ng new dashboard
$cd dashboard
$sudo ng serve
Password:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

But I am getting above erro which I don't understand.

Answer (score 8):

try with this command:
ng serve --port 4200  --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the localhost entry in your hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```